# Read .raw files from a folder and render it using vtk

Tags: c++, qt, vtk, itk

I need to read 55 number of .raw file which kept in a single folder with 1024x1024 dimensions and 16 bit depth. The same should be displayed using vtk and qt or itk and qt.

Answer (score 0):

You can construct a [NRRD](http://teem.sourceforge.net/nrrd/format.html#detached) or [MetaImage](https://itk.org/Wiki/ITK/MetaIO/Documentation#Reading_DICOM_and_Other_One-Slice-Per-File_Data_Formats) header to indicate metadata for this volume.